# absence of a file after new installation of cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I know this would similar to existing problems but please read it completely before judging.
i'm new in cakephp and after extracting the zip file in my root folder (wamp/www)
and refer to it in my browser it shows an error

> Error: MyfirstcakeController could not be found.
>   Error: Create the class MyfirstcakeController below in file:src\Controller\MyfirstcakeController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class MyfirstcakeController extends AppController
{

}
```

but when I go to the specified address there isn't a file with *MyfirstcakeController.php* name
I create a file with that name and copy the code inside it but after that other error appears.
it also say something is missing from the MyfirstcakeController class, I copy that code and past it inside the class but at the end it comes to a empty page and I can't access to database or other things.
I check all the solutions which similar to my case like enabling mod_rewrite.so and mbstring PHP extension and intl PHP extension but it doesn't solve the problem
according to books and my search in internet at end it should reach to the database tables that I create befor and ability to update them or anything else but it doesn't happen.
please someone tell me what's the problem and what should I do.
should I create the file manually or it should create automatically?
and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

fortunately I found a solution in cookbook of cakephp which is for version 3.2 of cakephp
first of all you shouldn't refer to the name of your database like i did. we should write the name of tables in database in address bar of browser, but before doing that there is a command we should run it to create necessary files.
for doing this first open *cmd* and navigate to **bin** directory between your cakephp directories then run the following command according to your table name in database
    `cake bake all table_name`
this command will generate the controllers, models and views files for our table.
you should do it for all of your tables.
then go to your browser and in address bar after directory name your cakephp files is located add a forward slash and your table name. you should see a page with links that enable you to add new record to table and so on
and don't forget before all these processes edit your *app.php* file in **config** directory and update *Datasources* array according to your database connectivity options.